# Spring application context in multiple tomcats

Tags: spring, tomcat8

If there are multiple web applications in different tomcats, how to configure same application context for all the tomcats

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand the question correctly. I guess you misunderstand some concepts. First, what is your package; is it war or jar. Do you use Spring MVC or Spring Boot (If you are new i suggest you to use Spring Boot). If you are using Spring MVC you are required to deploy your war to a servlet container like Tomcat. And if you want to deploy your applications to multiple tomcats, it is possible of course. However each application run on their own application context. These application contexts will have same beans and will be on same state when they are firstly initialized. As far as i know it is not possible to share one application context over multiple spring mvc applications and i think it doesn't make sense.

If you are using Spring Boot, your application will run on JVM with an embedded servlet container. In this case, your application is packaged in a JAR file with servlet container and you are not required to deploy the application. When you run the application both servlet container and your application context is initialized. In this situation, you can run multiple applications and as i said before these applications will have different application contexts.